# How to setup Nginx to proxy to two service on one machine?

Tags: python, ruby, nginx, reverse-proxy, microservices

I have written two micros services with python and ruby. The python one serves some api requests.  and the ruby one serves the other api requests.

the python one listens port 80 and can handle /users /feeds requests
the ruby one listens port 4567 and can handle /orders /products requests.

the following is my config file .but it does not work with nginx .

```
upstream midgard_api_cluster
 {
     server unix:/tmp/midgard_api.sock;
  }

upstream tradeapi {
    server    127.0.0.1:4567;
 }

server {
   listen        80;
server_name my.domain.name;
client_max_body_size 20M;

set $x_remote_addr $http_x_real_ip;
if ($x_remote_addr = "") {
    set $x_remote_addr $remote_addr;
}

access_log     /var/log/nginx/midgard/access_log ;
error_log     /var/log/nginx/midgard/error_log ;
charset utf-8;
location /static/ {
        root /opt/www/templates/;
        expires 30d;
    }

location / {
        error_page      502 503 504 /500.html;
        uwsgi_pass      midgard_api_cluster;
        include     uwsgi_params;

        # proxy_redirect      default;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $x_remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    Range $http_range;

        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_send_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 11;
    }

    location /products {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://tradeapi;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location /orders {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://tradeapi;

    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

}

Now , when i use

```
 curl http://my.domain.name/products
```

It got a 404 error and the request was directed to the python service .

and

```
curl http://my.domain.name:3000/products
```

can get the right response .

How can i setup the nginx configuration file and route the request to the ruby service ?

Answer (score 0):

`locations` are processed in order. The `/`-location matches before `/products` so the later is never reached. Put `/` at the end of the config file.

Comment: That is because prefix type location blocks, such as the two you have, are **NOT** processed in order and it does not matter where they appear in the config file. the type of location blocks matched in order of appearance are those defined by regular expressions.